# How to speed up excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below excel formula, but it often takes minutes to calculate. It is basically concatenating a bunch of columns into a string, along with a few other minor changes. Any suggestions for ways to improve speed?

```
=CONCAT( 'Calls'!$A$1, ",", 'Calls'!A31, ";",  'Calls'!$B$1, ",", TEXT('Calls'!B31, "mm/dd/yy"), ";",  'Calls'!$C$1, ",", 'Calls'!C31, ";",  'Calls'!$D$1, ",",TEXT( 'Calls'!D31, "mmmm dd, yyyy"), ";",  'Calls'!$E$1, ",", 'Calls'!E31, ";",  'Calls'!$F$1, ",", 'Calls'!F31, ";",  'Calls'!$G$1, ",", 'Calls'!G31, ";",  'Calls'!$H$1, ",", 'Calls'!H31, ";", 'Calls'!$I$1, ",", 'Calls'!I31, ";", 'Calls'!$J$1, ",", 'Calls'!J31, ";", 'Calls'!$K$1, ",", 'Calls'!K31, ";", 'Calls'!$L$1, ",", 'Calls'!L31, ";", 'Calls'!$M$1, ",", 'Calls'!M31, ";", 'Calls'!$N$1, ",", 'Calls'!N31, ";", 'Calls'!$P$1, ",", 'Calls'!P31, ";", 'Calls'!$O$1, ",", 'Calls'!O31, ";")
```

Comment: `='Calls'!$A$1:$O$1&","&'Calls'!A31:O31&";"` but it looks like you have an end goal of `Hstack('Calls'!$A$1:$O$1,'Calls'!A31:O31)`

Comment: Please include a representative data sample (as **text** which can be copy/pasted) along with your expected results from that sample data.

Comment: Concatenating shouldn't take minutes. If it isn't the _ONLY_ formula on the worksheet, it may take mintues to re-calculate all formulas. In short, the bottleneck might be other formulas if you use `Automatic` as calculation option.

Comment: I think, judging by the `$` in the header cells, you drag this along downwards. Maybe you can gain speed in this process. Do you use Office 365? Then you could spill it in one go for multiple rows: `=$A$1:$O$1&","&TEXT(A31:O32,"mm/dd/yy")&";"`

Comment: Is Power Query an option for you?